# Javascript - Regex : How to replace id in string with the same id plus number?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, find-occurrences

I have a string with multiple elements with id's like below:

```
var data = "<div id='1'></div><input type='text' id='2'/>";
```

Now I'm using this regex to find all the id's in the string:

```
var reg = /id="([^"]+)"/g;
```

Afterwards I want to replace all those id's with a new id. Something like this:

```
data = data.replace(reg, + 'id="' + reg2 + '_' + numCompare + '"');
```

I want `reg2`, as seen above, to return the value of the id's.
**I'm not too familiar with Regular Expressions, so how can I go about doing this?**

Comment: Do you have jquery sourced? Could make this super easy and without trying to use regex on dom, which you should avoid.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using jquery

Comment: Please note that IDs that start with a number are not valid HTML

Comment: @Dancrumb They are in HTML5. But it still shouldn't be encouraged

Comment: The ID's start with a string, then a number is added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using regex, parse it and loop through elements. Try:

```
var data = "<div id='1'></div><div id='asdf'><input type='text' id='2'/></div>",
    numCompare = 23,
    div = document.createElement("div"),
    i, cur;

div.innerHTML = data;

function updateId(parent) {
    var children = parent.children;
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        cur = children[i];
        if (cur.nodeType === 1 && cur.id) {
            cur.id = cur.id + "_" + numCompare;
        }
        updateId(cur);
    }
}

updateId(div);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RbuaG/3/

This checks to see if the `id` is set in the first place, and only then will it modify it.

Also, it is safe in case the HTML contains a comment node (where IE 6-8 does include comment nodes in `.children`).

Also, it walks through all children of all elements. In your example, you only had one level of elements (no nested). But in my fiddle, I nest the `<input />` and it is still modified.

To get the get the updated HTML, use `div.innerHTML`.

With jQuery, you can try:

```
var data = "<div id='1'></div><div id='asdf'><input type='text' id='2'/></div>",
    numCompare = 23,
    div = $("<div>"),
    i, cur;

div.append(data);

div.find("[id]").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("id", function (index, attr) {
        return attr + "_" + numCompare;
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tXFwh/5/

While it's valid to have the `id` start with and/or be a number, you should change the `id` of the elements to be a normal identifier.

References:

- `.children`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children
- `.nodeType`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType
- `jQuery.find()`: http://api.jquery.com/find/
- `jQuery.attr()`: http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- `jQuery.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
.replace(/id='(.*?)'/g, 'id="$1_' + numCompare + '"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery (further to your commments).

```
var data = "<div id='1'></div><input type='text' id='2'/>";
var output = $("<div></div>").html(data); // Convert string to jQuery object
output.find("[id]").each(function() { // Select all elements with an ID
   var target = $(this);
   var id = target.attr("id"); // Get the ID
   target.attr("id", id + "_" + numCompare); // Set the id
});
console.log(output.html());
```

This is much better than using regex on HTML ([Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)), is faster (although can be further improved by having a more direct selector than `$("[id]")` such as giving the elements a class).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/georeith/E6Hn7/10/

Comment: Not really going to help with as he said: "I have a string with multiple elements with id's like below:"

Comment: @StefanRay Can convert that string to a jQuery object... perform manipulation... convert back. jQuery works in memory to.

Comment: Please give a reason when downvoting... this works - nuff said.

Answer (score 1):

Regex probably isn't the right way to do this, here is an example that uses jQuery:

```
var htmlstring = "<div id='1'></div><input type='text' id='2'/>";

var $dom = $('<div>').html(htmlstring);

$('[id]', $dom).each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '_' + numCompare);
});

htmlstring = $dom.html();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fYb3U/